# jQuery intercept form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I have number of conditions i'd like to check before submitting a form so I've created:

```
$("Step2_UpdateCartForm").submit(function () {
    if (!procssingEmails) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

And I have a number of events that could result in a form submission so i have something like:

```
function fireUpdateCart() {
    if (isUpdateCartPending) {
        clearCartOptionDefaultValues();
        $("#Step2_UpdateCartForm").submit();
    }
}
```

in a few different places. I'm expecting the above statement to send processing to that first code block but instead, the form is being submitted.

Am i wrong to expect my validation block to be processed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a "#" identifier from your event definition.  This is the likely cause of your problem.  The first line should read:

```
$("#Step2_UpdateCartForm").submit(function () {

   ^
```

Comment: gawd i hate those mistakes - can i blame it on Monday?

Answer (score 6):

There's a missing # in your selector. You should use the following:

```
$("#Step2_UpdateCartForm").submit(function () {
    if (!procssingEmails) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

And BTW, maybe your "procssingEmails" is misspelled, isn't it?